# Python Split Nested Dictionary with No Key Value Pairs

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary with no key-value pairs. I am trying to separate them into a dataframe with separate columns and do not need to preserve the original structure. The intention is to separate each visible row into an actual row in a dataframe with the columns being named `word`, `start_time`, and `end_time`. I have tried to flatten it with `flatdict`, but since there is no named key it does not work.

Here is an example of the nested dictionary stored in the variable `word_timestamps`.

```
[[['hello', 3.06, 3.32]],
 [['hi', 4.2, 4.32],
  ['can', 4.54, 4.62],
  ['i', 4.66, 4.7],
  ['please', 4.74, 4.86],
  ['speak', 4.9, 5.04],
  ['to', 5.06, 5.14],
  ['ashley', 5.2, 5.56]],
 [['yeah', 6.84, 6.94],
  ['may', 7.04, 7.12],
  ['i', 7.12, 7.12],
  ['ask', 7.18, 7.28],
  ["who's", 7.36, 7.46],
  ['calling', 7.54, 7.86]]]
```

I can view individual "rows" of this successfully using this format `word_timestamps[0]`. This returns:

```
[['hello', 3.06, 3.32]]
```

Or I can access a single word using `word_timestamps[0][0][0]` which returns `'hello'`.

How do I flatten the dictionary and get rid of the entire structure?

Edit: added everything below.

I used `[value for sublist in word_timestamps for value in sublist]` which returned the same answer as below. The full code used was:

```
df_word_timestamps = pd.DataFrame([value for sublist in word_timestamps for value in sublist], columns =["word", "from", "to"])
```

Which results in:

```
    word    from    to
0   hello   3.06    3.32
1   hi  4.20    4.32
2   can 4.54    4.62
3   i   4.66    4.70
4   please  4.74    4.86
... ... ... ...
1179    right   399.98  400.08
1180    bye-bye 400.64  400.86
1181    thanks  401.70  401.92
1182    bye 402.02  402.16
1183    bye 402.88  403.04
```

The reason I did this was so I could join a second dataframe on the matching start/stop times. The second dataframe contains the person that spoke these words. Together I can create a labeled transcript.

Comment: There are no dictionaries there at all.  You have a set of nested lists.  What is it you really want?  You want to have one list containing a bunch of three-element lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically "adding" a set of sublists.

```
word_timestamps = [[['hello', 3.06, 3.32]],
 [['hi', 4.2, 4.32],
  ['can', 4.54, 4.62],
  ['i', 4.66, 4.7],
  ['please', 4.74, 4.86],
  ['speak', 4.9, 5.04],
  ['to', 5.06, 5.14],
  ['ashley', 5.2, 5.56]],
 [['yeah', 6.84, 6.94],
  ['may', 7.04, 7.12],
  ['i', 7.12, 7.12],
  ['ask', 7.18, 7.28],
  ["who's", 7.36, 7.46],
  ['calling', 7.54, 7.86]]]

combine = sum(word_timestamps, [])
print(combine)
```

Comment: Interesting, that makes sense. I just realized I had a dictionary of lists in the original variable and unpacked this portion already, so it's really a nested list. I just used list comprehension to get the same result--what are your thoughts on using `[value for sublist in word_timestamps for value in sublist]` instead?

Comment: That also works.  Personal preference.